# Does squaring all unitary matrices give the identity matrix?

Tags: matrices

All examples of unitary matrices that I've seen square to give the identity matrix, but I've never seen this explicitly listed as a property of unitary matrices.

Is this true for all unitary matrices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly not, consider the matrix
$$J := \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}.$$
Since $J^* J = I$, it is unitary, but $J^2 = -I$.

Comment: I think I might be misunderstanding some fundamental thing.  What is the difference between $J*J$ and $J^2$?

Comment: Me too. Aren't they the same?

Comment: $J^2$ is the ordinary matrix product.  $J^*$ is the complex conjugate of the transpose of $J$.  So $J^*J$ is the ordinary matrix product of $J^*$ times $J$.

Comment: Oh i see that the * is elevated, and that your latex has it as ^*, not as *.  Thanks!

Comment: Just saw this exchange---thanks for clearing this up, @Michael. (Perhaps a similar issue is the motivation of the downvote?)

Comment: Twasn't me, so I don't know.

Comment: @Michael Sorry, my wording was probably unclear, I didn't mean to suggest you may have downvoted (which would have seemed unlikely, anyway, as you interpreted the answer as I intended).

Answer (score 4):

The examples you have seen must have been Hermitian; in fact
any two of the properties unitary, involution, Hermitian:
$$
 A^*A=I, \quad A^2 = I, \quad A^* = A
$$
imply the third.

Answer (score 0):

For matrix$A^{-1}=A^T$ and column vectors have unit magnitude, it is unitary matrix. If we could do $A^2=I => A=A^{-1} => A=A^T$ if A is symmetrical and unitary then $A^2 =I$.